# How to put vertical dots above and below and centered a horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf

in my memory layout diagram I want to have vertical three dots above and below
the outlined memory cell.

Is there a more elegant way to calculate the surrounding horizontal and vertical lines?

Thanks  in advance

Marcel

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=7mm] (opc)              {Operations};
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=7mm,minimum width=15mm] (operanda) [right=0pt of opc]  {$\#42$};
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=7mm,minimum width=15mm] (operandb) [right=0pt of operanda] {$\$1000$};
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=7mm,minimum width=15mm] (operandc) [right=0pt of operandb] {$\$2000$};

\draw[red,thick] (-0.95,0.35) -- (5.5,0.35);
\draw[red,thick] (-0.95,-0.35) -- (5.5,-0.35);

\draw[red,thick] (-0.95,2.0) -- (-0.95,-2.0);
\draw[red,thick] (5.5,2.0) -- (5.5,-2.0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, but where this dots should be?

Comment: If you just want to divide the box, you might use `rectangle split`, which requires `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}`.

Comment: @Zarko: You have read my mind ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just guessing:

[image]

At least the code is shorter ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
      start chain = A going right,
      base/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum height=7mm, outer sep=0pt},
       box/.style = {base,minimum width=15mm, on chain=A},
dottedline/.style = {ultra thick, loosely dotted,shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm}
                    ]    
\node[base, on chain=A] (opc)       {Operations};
\node[box] (operanda)   {$\#42$};
\node[box] (operandb)   {$\$1000$};
\node[box] (operandc)   {$\$2000$};
%
\node[draw=red,thick,inner sep=0pt, fit=(A-1) (A-4)]  (operand) {};% <-- added missing node name
%
\draw[dottedline] (operand.north) -- + (0, 7mm);
\draw[dottedline] (operand.south) -- + (0,-7mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:** ups, in the *mwe* wasn't the last (by which the image is generated) ... in it the name of red box is missed. now is corrected.

Comment: This looks really good! How can I get now the vertical lines on the left and right side?

Comment: @MarcelSchaible, i'm glad that my guessing was correct.

Comment: Almost there. When I render the diagram the dots are not centered to the large box and I am puzzled how to add the original vertical lines on the left and the right side of the box.

Comment: I guess you meant

    \draw[dottedline] (operanda.north) -- + (0, 7mm);
    \draw[dottedline] (operanda.south) -- + (0,-7mm);

Comment: @MarcelSchaible; no, i put `dottrdline`s  to centere of the red box (about this you aren't clear in your question. however, you can move those lines where you like to have, for example as you said in your comment above.

Comment: Yep my fault. Hard to put intended layouts into words. I have added a hopefully clarifying image to the question. But I am still puzzled how the you have to achieved to center the dots?

Comment: upds, now i see that the code is not the recent. actually, mwe doesn't work since the name of the red box is missing. corrected now.